# Sort file/lines by first word with Python

Tags: python

How do i sort a file so that the basis of sorting is only the first word? The first word is not a fixed length.

I am trying:

```
f = open("temp", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
print lines
lines.sort()
f2 = open('out.txt', 'w')
f2.write(''.join(lines)) # Write a sequence of strings to a file
f2.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: I am sure you are supposed to get an error

Comment: i see that, the list nees to be converted to string. fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sort by the first word in each line, you need to split the lines and use the first word as a key in a sort:

```
lines.sort(key=lambda a_line: a_line.split()[0])
```

Comment: just for my education, say i wanted to sort by first two words, how would i modify that?

Comment: Just return two values from the lambda: e.g. `lines.sort(key=lambda a_line: (a_line.split()[0], a_line.split()[1])`

Comment: @Marcin `a_line.split()[:2]` would be much shorter and easier to read. Also it doesn't raise `IndexError` if a line has less than two words, like the example in your comment does.

Answer (score 3):

can you replace the `lines.sort()` with:

```
lines.sort(key=lambda x: x.split()[0] if len(x.split()) >0 else None)
```

also; you need a condition in a `key` for any possible blank new lines; otherwise you will face error(`IndexError: list index out of range`).